# which is the correct table name for this content provider? Android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

i have looked at many examples for content provider. and when the database is created the table name does not match.  in the example below the table is declared as "Country" in the creation of the SQLite database

```
  public static final String SQLITE_TABLE = "Country";
```

however, the table name is described as "countries" in the URI

```
  // create content URIs from the authority by appending path to database table
  public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = 
  Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY + "/countries");
```

the table name is after the authority in the URI, so in this example the table name is supposed to be "countries",  that is different from what is declared during the creation of the database

which of these is the correct table name,  `Country` or `countries`?

```
 public class MyContentProvider extends ContentProvider{

  private MyDatabaseHelper dbHelper;

 private static final int ALL_COUNTRIES = 1;
 private static final int SINGLE_COUNTRY = 2;

// authority is the symbolic name of your provider
// To avoid conflicts with other providers, you should use 
// Internet domain ownership (in reverse) as the basis of your provider authority. 
private static final String AUTHORITY = "com.as400samplecode.contentprovider";

// create content URIs from the authority by appending path to database table
public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = 
 Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY + "/countries");

// a content URI pattern matches content URIs using wildcard characters:
// *: Matches a string of any valid characters of any length.
// #: Matches a string of numeric characters of any length.
private static final UriMatcher uriMatcher;
static {
 uriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
 uriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "countries", ALL_COUNTRIES);
 uriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "countries/#", SINGLE_COUNTRY);
}


 public class CountriesDb {

 public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
 public static final String KEY_CODE = "code";
 public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
 public static final String KEY_CONTINENT = "continent";

 private static final String LOG_TAG = "CountriesDb";
 public static final String SQLITE_TABLE = "Country";

  private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
  "CREATE TABLE if not exists " + SQLITE_TABLE + " (" +
  KEY_ROWID + " integer PRIMARY KEY autoincrement," +
  KEY_CODE + "," +
  KEY_NAME + "," +
  KEY_CONTINENT + "," +
 " UNIQUE (" + KEY_CODE +"));";

  public static void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
  Log.w(LOG_TAG, DATABASE_CREATE);
  db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
  }

   public static void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
   Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
   + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
   db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + SQLITE_TABLE);
   onCreate(db);
  }

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a problem with this code

The content provider is just a public interface to that database table. The terms do not have to match perfectly.

It is a standard practice to make your table names singular. It is also a common practice to make functions based on table names plural. Sometimes, this is even done automatically by code generators.

In the case of SQLite and Android uris from Content Providers however, our tools are not that sophisticated. That is why, in the second line of the uriMatcher, the wording used really doesn't make much sense for us humans:

```
uriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "countries/#", SINGLE_COUNTRY);
```

Comment: so, I can select any name for this variable instead of "countries"?